# $\int_{0}^{\infty}(n+1)(1-e^{-x})^{n-1}e^{x(it-1)}e^{-x}dx$

Tags: integration

I have to compute the following integral

$\int_{0}^{\infty}(n+1)(1-e^{-x})^{n-1}e^{x(it-1)}e^{-x}dx$

which should be equal to $\frac{1-it}{n}\int_{0}^{\infty}(n+1)(1-e^{-x})^{n}e^{itx}e^{-x}dx$.

Any idea how to compute it ??

Comment: [Integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts). In the latter integral, differentiate $(1-e^{-x})^n$ and integrate the remaining factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I=\int_{0}^{\infty}(n+1)(1-e^{-x})^{n-1}e^{x(it-1)}e^{-x}dx$

you can see thet $ \frac{d}{dx}( \frac{1}{n}(1-e^{-x})^{n})=(1-e^{-x})^{n-1}e^{-x}$

$$I=\left. \frac{n+1}{n}(1-e^{-x})^{n}e^{x(it-1)} \right\rvert_{0}^{\infty} - \int_{0}^{\infty}(n+1)\frac{1}{n}(1-e^{-x})^{n}(it-1)e^{x(it-1)}dx$$

as we have $\left. \frac{n+1}{n}(1-e^{-x})^{n}e^{x(it-1)} \right\rvert_{0}^{\infty}=0 \quad because \quad   e^{ixt} \quad bounded \quad and \quad  e^{-x} \rightarrow 0 \quad when \quad x \rightarrow \infty$ 
so

$$I= - \frac{(it-1)}{n}\int_{0}^{\infty}(n+1)\frac{1}{n}(1-e^{-x})^{n}(it-1)e^{x(it-1)}dx$$
$$I= \frac{(1-it)}{n}\int_{0}^{\infty}(n+1)\frac{1}{n}(1-e^{-x})^{n}(it-1)e^{x(it-1)}dx$$